# Plotting a piecewise symbolic expression in MATLAB using ezplot

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have created the following symbolic integral:

```
syms x; 
syms t; 
int(1./((1-t.*x).^3),t,0,1)

ans =
    piecewise([x = 1, Inf], [not 1/x in (0, 1) and x 1, -(x/2 - 1)/(x - 1)^2])
```

which results in a piecewise function definition. Now I want to plot this integral using the `ezplot` function, but this leads to an error:

```
Error using ezplot (line 162)
piecewise([1/x in Dom::Interval([0], [1]), -int(1/(t*x - 1)^3, t, 0, 1)], 
   [~1/x in Dom::Interval([0], [1]), -(x - 2)/(2*(x - 1)^2)]) 
   cannot be plotted in the xy-plane.

Error in sym/ezplot (line 61)
   h = ezplot(fhandle(f));
```

How can I plot this piecewise symbolic integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I could not find any evidence by Mathworks, it seems that [`ezplot`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezplot.html) does *not* work together with piecewise symbolic functions (Source: there are a few open questions on exactly this topic in the Matlab help forum).

In this answer I am presenting a work-around, which works for explicit, invertible functions, i.e. it will fail for stuff like `x^2 + y^2 = 1` or `y^2 = y^4` , and similar stuff. In this special case (which I assume is used most often), one can manually generate a `x`-vector and calculate the corresponding `y`-values using the [`subs`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) function.

The default range for `ezplot` is `[-2pi, 2pi]`. The number of points depends strongly on the function, but with around 1000 points, a reasonably smooth plot should be created. *Note*: This should produce the default `ezplot` behavior. If you have further knowledge about the function, i.e. value ranges etc., you should definitely use this to create the `x` vector.

```
xp = -2*pi : 0.01: 2*pi;
yp = subs(f, x, xp);
plot(xp,yp);
```